# Calibrate with cph function (with external validation)

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have two questions for calibrate with cph function.
My data have 5 independent variables(from BMI to RT), and 2 dependent variables (time, event).

```
> head(data)
   BMI Taxanes Surgery LND RT Event Time
1  19       0       0   2  5     0  98
2  20       0       0   3  3     0  97
3  21       0       0   8  2     0  17
4  18       0       0   1  3     0  35
5  20       1       0   3  1     0  27
6  20       1       0   2  3     1   2

> str(data)
 $ BMI    : num  19 20 21 18 20 20 20 ...
 $ Taxanes: int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Surgery: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ LND    : int  2 3 8 1 3 2 2 2 5 2 ...
 $ RT     : Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 3 2 3 1 3  ...
 $ Event  : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Time   : num  98 97 17 35 27 2 22  ...
```

(1) With this data, I did survival analysis with cph model. And I want to make a calibration plot using this data. But I got an error which *"Error in x(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default"*. I was finding lots of material. But I don't know the reason for this error. Even if I found the calibrate function in web, But I can't find for the element 'y'. please help me for this question.

```
> ddist <- datadist(data)
> options(datadist='ddist')
> 
> fit = cph(Surv(Time,Event) ~ BMI + Surgery + Taxanes + RT + LND, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv=TRUE, dxy=TRUE, time.inc=36)
> plot(calibrate(fit))
Using Cox survival estimates at  36 Days

**Error in x(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default**
```

(2) Eventually I want to do external validation for this cph model(fit). 
If new data name is kind of dat2 (which has the same variable with data), then what is the observed and predicted survival? I know that the predicted value calculate like this code

```
val<-val.surv(fit, newdata=dat2, S=Surv(dat2$Time,dat2$Event))
```

But how I get a actual(observed) survival in new data(dat2)? Please help for this problem. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You should first make a separate calibrate object and see if the error is coming from the ‘calibrate’ or ‘plot’ call.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your comment. As you comment, the error is coming from the 'calibrate' function. I transfered 'calibrate.cph' function. But the error is still coming. 
Would you recommend for an external validation function 
which is applicable to calibration? Thanks you so much:)

Comment: I have never seen that error with the calibrate function, but I cannot offer further insights into possible cause. Do you get the error with a subset of the data. (Recommend basic debugging strategies in an effort to create [MCVE].

Comment: @42- Maybe I need to check the detailed code in the calibrate function. Anyway thank you for your comment and debugging strategies.